# JMS Set Reply To Queue Manager

Tags: jms, mq

I want to set the required queue manager when sending a JMS message.
Currently I am able to set the destination queue in the JMSReplyTO method, but I don't know how to also specify the queue manager.

```
TextMessage message = queueSession.createTextMessage();
message.setText(messageStr);
message.setJMSReplyTo(destinationQueue);
queueSender.send(message);
```

Comment: Which MQ are you using?  It's not RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ...

Comment: Hi, it's Active MQ provided by WebSphere

Comment: Ah.  Well, ActiveMQ may be the provider, but the classes you mention aren't native ActiveMQ.  What is the full package and class name of the connection factory?  Does it have a setBrokerQueueManager method?

Comment: I've updated my answer with ActiveMQ details.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go (for WebSphere MQ):

```
   MQQueue replyToQ = new MQQueue(QMgrName, ReplyQueue);
   Destination replyTo = (Destination) replyToQ;
   message.setJMSReplyTo(replyTo);
```

Comment: Ya, You are right.. I already implemented this solution and it's working fine.. Thanks a lot Roger

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which MQ you're using, but your class names look like WebSphere's ones, so I'll guess that's it.

The queue manager name can be set on the connection factory, *before* you get a connection from it.  Use MQConnectionFactory#setBrokerQueueManager(String).

The IBM javadocs for the method are [here, on publib](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/uj28320_.htm).

If you're using ActiveMQ, then you can't set the queue manager, since ActiveMQ doesn't support that abstraction.  You could name your broker to be whatever you want your messages to use as their queue manager, since ActiveMQ brokers and MQ managers are roughly equivalent.  I have no idea if that will help at all, though.  You may have to switch to using WebSphere's own MQ.